# How to do a function on a list of parametes parallel in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a list of parameters and a function and I want to run this function on these parameters parallel, I used paralleljs in nodejs but it does not recognize global parameters inside it and I want to use other parameters inside it. my code is like this:

```
let mysockets = new parallel(socketList);
          let mydata = mysockets.data;
          mysockets.map(function(mydata){
            if (mydata !== msg.socketId){
              io.to(mydata).emit("new message", msg.Message)
            }
          }).then(function(){
            console.log(mydata);
          })
```

msg is an object I defined before this and it has socketId in it, but when I run this code it says :

> ReferenceError: msg is not defined

What should I do? What am I doing wrong? If paralleljs has this problem is there another solution to do a function on a values of an array parallel?

thanks in advance.

Comment: we probably need to see the full code, msg is clearly not defined either because msg is locally scoped elsewhere, instantiated after this code is executed or something else.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I am sure that msg is defined, I logged it before parallel and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not need to use `paralleljs`, you can try [bluebird promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

```
Promise.map(mysockets, function(socket) {
    // Promise.map awaits for returned promises as well.
    return // Async function here.;
}).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
});
```

You can also checkout [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) and [Promise.each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html).

Comment: I get the error that  the promise.map is not a function!!, I have another question, does this do the function inside promise parallel? I really need to do it parallel.